# Google Play services out of date error using Google Maps API

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services, android-service

I was testing an Android app in an smartphone with Android 4.0.3 and works fine but now I'm testing the app on other smartphone with Android 4.4.3 and I have a problem.

This is my log:

```
08-04 19:58:44.028: I/Process(22072): Sending signal. PID: 22072 SIG: 9
08-04 19:58:44.184: I/SQLiteAssetHelper(22156): successfully opened database dumpd
08-04 19:58:44.257: I/Adreno-EGL(22156): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:320>: EGL 1.4      QUALCOMM build:  (N/A)
08-04 19:58:44.257: I/Adreno-EGL(22156): OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version:  E031.24.00.00
08-04 19:58:44.257: I/Adreno-EGL(22156): Build Date: 11/12/13 Tue
08-04 19:58:44.257: I/Adreno-EGL(22156): Local Branch: 
08-04 19:58:44.257: I/Adreno-EGL(22156): Remote Branch: 
08-04 19:58:44.257: I/Adreno-EGL(22156): Local Patches: 
08-04 19:58:44.257: I/Adreno-EGL(22156): Reconstruct Branch: 
08-04 19:58:44.282: D/OpenGLRenderer(22156): Enabling debug mode 0
08-04 20:05:30.773: D/dalvikvm(22567): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 183K, 7% free 16021K/17216K, paused 16ms, total 17ms
08-04 20:05:30.783: I/dalvikvm-heap(22567): Grow heap (frag case) to 22.810MB for 5379856-byte allocation
08-04 20:05:32.571: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(22567): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 4452000 but found 4033530
08-04 20:05:32.576: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(22567): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 4452000 but found 4033530
08-04 20:05:32.582: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(22567): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 4452000 but found 4033530
08-04 20:05:32.588: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(22567): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 4452000 but found 4033530
08-04 20:05:32.593: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(22567): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 4452000 but found 4033530
08-04 20:05:32.598: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(22567): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 4452000 but found 4033530
08-04 20:05:32.604: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(22567): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 4452000 but found 4033530
08-04 20:05:32.610: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(22567): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 4452000 but found 4033530
08-04 20:05:32.616: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(22567): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 4452000 but found 4033530
08-04 20:05:32.635: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(22567): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 4452000 but found 4033530
08-04 20:05:32.641: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(22567): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 4452000 but found 4033530
08-04 20:05:32.701: D/AndroidRuntime(22567): Shutting down VM
08-04 20:05:32.701: W/dalvikvm(22567): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41649d40)
08-04 20:05:32.709: E/AndroidRuntime(22567): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-04 20:05:32.709: E/AndroidRuntime(22567): Process: com.example.uem_pfg_rutas, PID: 22567
08-04 20:05:32.709: E/AndroidRuntime(22567): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity  ComponentInfo{com.example.uem_pfg_rutas/com.example.uem_pfg_rutas.VerRutaActivity}:  java.lang.NullPointerException: CameraUpdateFactory is not initialized
08-04 20:05:32.709: E/AndroidRuntime(22567):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)
08-04 20:05:32.709: E/AndroidRuntime(22567):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
08-04 20:05:32.709: E/AndroidRuntime(22567):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
08-04 20:05:32.709: E/AndroidRuntime(22567):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
08-04 20:05:32.709: E/AndroidRuntime(22567):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-04 20:05:32.709: E/AndroidRuntime(22567):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-04 20:05:32.709: E/AndroidRuntime(22567):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
08-04 20:05:32.709: E/AndroidRuntime(22567):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-04 20:05:32.709: E/AndroidRuntime(22567):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-04 20:05:32.709: E/AndroidRuntime(22567):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
08-04 20:05:32.709: E/AndroidRuntime(22567):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
08-04 20:05:32.709: E/AndroidRuntime(22567):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-04 20:05:32.709: E/AndroidRuntime(22567): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: CameraUpdateFactory is not initialized
08-04 20:05:32.709: E/AndroidRuntime(22567):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.fq.b(Unknown Source)
08-04 20:05:32.709: E/AndroidRuntime(22567):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory.ie(Unknown Source)
08-04 20:05:32.709: E/AndroidRuntime(22567):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(Unknown Source)
08-04 20:05:32.709: E/AndroidRuntime(22567):    at com.example.uem_pfg_rutas.VerRutaActivity.onCreate(VerRutaActivity.java:97)
08-04 20:05:32.709: E/AndroidRuntime(22567):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
08-04 20:05:32.709: E/AndroidRuntime(22567):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
08-04 20:05:32.709: E/AndroidRuntime(22567):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2173)
08-04 20:05:32.709: E/AndroidRuntime(22567):    ... 11 more
```

And this is the code when i think  i have the problem:

```
CameraUpdate camUpd2 = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(posicion, 13F);
GoogleMap mapa =((SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map2)).getMap();
mapa.animateCamera(camUpd2);
```

The declaration of the variable "posición" is:

```
LatLng posición = null;
Coordenada coordenada = ruta.getListadoCoordenadas().get(j);
String latitud = coordenada.getLatitud();
String longitud = coordenada.getLongitud();
posicion = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(latitud),Double.parseDouble(longitud));
```

I think that is a problem with the Google Map api but i'm not sure.

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
08-04 20:05:32.571: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(22567): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 4452000 but found 4033530
```

You can resolve this by either updating the Google Play Services app on the device, or you can use an older version of the Google Play Services library in your project.

The second option is not recommended, although it can be a solution when you have no other choice due to external factors, such as target device age.

Comment: Working for me!

Answer (score 0):

check your variables. Are these two the same variables?

> LatLng posición = null;
>
> posicion = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(latitud),Double.parseDouble(longitud));

if so check "posicion" is not null before calling

> CameraUpdate camUpd2 = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(posicion, 13F);

Answer (score 0):

ok, solved!

The problem was that my new mobile didn't have the last version of Google Services, i updated the mobile and the problem is solved.